# Getting Hibernate Template object as null

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring boot application. I want to use Hibernate Template. In my HibernateAdaptor class, I am getting the HibernateTemplate object as null. Looks like Spring is not able to inject the Hibernate Template. Am i missing something?

Following is the configuration file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  <beansxmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="MyURL"></property>
        <property name="username" value="user"></property>
        <property name="password" value="pass!"></property>

    </bean><bean id="hibernate3AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>        
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        <value>class1</value>
        <valueclass2</value>
</list>
</property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop> 
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>  
            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>  

    **<bean id="hibernateAdapter"
        class="com.yoku.server.core.db.adapter.HibernateAdapter">
        <property name="template" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
    </bean>**

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate3AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

Following is the class

```
package com.server.core.db.adapter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import com.yoku.server.infra.logger.ILogger;
import com.yoku.server.infra.logger.LoggerFactory;

public class HibernateAdapter<T> {

    HibernateTemplate template;

    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }
    private static final ILogger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(HibernateAdapter.class);

    public Object fetchByID(Class<T> entityClass, Serializable id) {

        logger.info("Template Object--------------------------" + template);
        return template.get(entityClass, id);
    }

}
```

Getting Following Exception:

```
INFO  c.y.s.c.s.product.ProductService - Template Object--------------------------null
Dec 25, 2015 10:10:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.server.core.db.adapter.HibernateAdapter.fetchByID(HibernateAdapter.java:33)
    at com.server.core.services.product.ProductService.getFashionProduct(ProductService.java:281)
    at com.server.core.services.product.ProductService.readProductDetails(ProductService.java:261)
    at com.server.rest.services.merchant.product.MerchantProductController.readproductDetails(MerchantProductController.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do you have some error?

Comment: updated the description with the Error

Comment: Show how you are using this template, my guess you are creating a new instance yourself instead of using/inject the one from the spring application context.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are using a Spring managed instance of the `HibernateAdapter` class. If you are instantiating the object yourself rather than using a Spring managed instance then Spring won't/can't inject your dependency.

To get more detailed responses perhaps include a full error message and and example of the code (usage of the `HibernateAdapter` class) which causes the error.

Comment: HibernateAdapter<Product> adapter=new HibernateAdapter();
  Product productFashion = (Product) adapter.fetchByID(Product.class, (Serializable)productId);

This code is calling that method. When i did logger.info, ican see that template object as null.

Comment: Calling `new` creates your own instance of the class rather than one managed by the Spring Framework. If you're not using Spring managed object then Spring won't inject anything. In whatever class your are making the `new` call, instead define a member variable of that class `@Autowired HibernateAdapter hibernateAdapter`, Spring will inject the class as defined in your config. Annotate the `HibernateAdapter` constructor with the `@Autowired` annotation to have the `HibernateTemplate` from your properties file injected.

Comment: @turboemy 

I have Added this to my service class:

Autowired
 private HibernateAdapter hibernateAdapter;


 public void setHibernateAdapter(HibernateAdapter hibernateAdapter) {
  this.hibernateAdapter = hibernateAdapter;
 }

And this to Hibernate Adaptor Class

public class HibernateAdapter<T> {

 Autowired
 HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
 
 
 public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
  this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
 }

Now getting hibernateAdapter as Null

Comment: You should not have any setter methods, since you don't ever want to set these objects. You want Spring to inject them.

It may be Spring is not scanning your classes, add the `context` namespace and locations to the Spring config, along with e.g. `<context:component-scan base-package="com.server.core" />` . This will tell Spring to scan your package for annotations. Annotate any classes with annotations in their body with an `@Service` annotation. You will need to read some of the docs and tutorials to understand what is going on here, I wouldn't advise blindly following my instruction.